# How to successfully unload classes when those classes are potentially in use?

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have built in my application the ability to reload classes. However, I need to clarification on the behaviour of the class loader.

Let me explain what I know and then ask the questions...

What I do is provide a special jar that is loaded by a custom classloader. Then during the bootstrap of the jar a bunch of spring beans are created and the ones which implement certain interfaces get registered for use by the central app.

Now I kick off a process in the application which uses these new classes. I can successfully unload the "jar", change classes in the jar and reload and I get the changes. Unloading in class loader parlance means making the class loader that loaded the classes unreachable - this causes any classes loaded by that class loader to be unreachable and thus effectively unloaded.

However, from what I know so far, once the vm has loaded the class it stores it in some shared space so does not have to load it again.

The issue that I have is that sometimes the unload and reload of a new class does not work. The old class stays around. It stands to reason that if I unload a class loader (i.e. make the class loader unreachable) and one of the classes in that class loader is currently in use (an object of that type exists) then the class cannot be unloaded.

Is this true? It seems to be true in practice.

If that is so, how do I successfully unload classes that are in use at the time the class loader goes unreachable. Could I for example, put a weak reference on each class so I can detect when the class goes unreachable and act when the class goes unreachable? (not sure what action I could take though).

**Update in response to @Kayaman**

My use case is that I have the core application and then based on the customers requirements I can load different classes that implement known interfaces in the core application (so they can be accessed). Then the core application kicks off various processes which use these classes. The big strength of this is that I can update these plugin classes without doing a big redeploy and every customer does not need every one of these. The problem comes in when I want to load a new version of one of these and  the current version is in use. Kinda stands to reason that this is not possible.

**Conclusion**

@Kayamam many thanks for your consult. It has been very helpful. This has codified my thinking somewhat. The conclusion is that no matter what technique I use you cannot ever, with the VM the way it is, reload a class for which there is currently a strongly reachable object. For some of my reloads I have control over these objects as I can make them unreachable before I unload and reload but for other classes I cannot do this... that is where my problem lies. What I need to do is to ring fence the objects of the classes that I wish to reload so that I can the process that is using them to pause while I reload the classes for those objects.

Comment: "once the vm has loaded the class it stores it in some shared space " - I assume you're refering to Java 8's metaspace or Java 7's (and below) PermGen space, aren't you?

Comment: Plugin architecture is a pretty old invention. Like I said, you can load a new version, but the old version won't be unloaded before it's not used anymore (but that just means at one point you'll have both in use until the older one gets "finished"). My links below should provide at least a starting point to do it in a Spring way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you said, in order to unload a class, you need to get rid of the classloader. For example `URLClassLoader` can be used to load classes, and then null out the reference to make it eligible for GC and therefore unload the classes it loaded.

However, all classes know which classloader loaded them. That means that if you've got instances of your classes in use, they have a reference to the `Class` which has a reference to the `ClassLoader` and will prevent it from being collected and classes being unloaded. This is understandable, since having an object without a class would be quite an interesting situation.

So for a full reload you need to get rid of old instances and get rid of the classloader. That also avoids situations where you get mysterious exceptions about `MyClass != MyClass`.

`WeakReference` (or `PhantomReference` would probably be better here) would allow you to notice when your existing objects get collected, you just need to make sure you're tracking them all.

Spring adds to the complexity here, so I strongly recommend spending some time imagining that this approach is impossible, and to see if Spring has something that could be used to fulfil your business requirement. After all it does a lot of classloading itself, so you might be reinventing the wheel in a less clear way.

With quick Googling I found this http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-hotswapping.html which mentions among other things [Spring Loaded](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-loaded) which can apparently do class reloading and then some.

Comment: Could I not use the weak reference to work out when the classes are no longer in use. This would be especially possible after the class loader goes unreachable. In other words, I'd make the class loader unreachable and then pause while i wait for all the classes loaded by that class loader to go unreachable as that would mean they are no longer in use and I can reload them. Although chances are it is the reference to the class that keeps the class loader around.

Comment: hmmm... a better approach might be to focus on the class loader as surely it is the in use classes that are keeping the class loader around. Thus if a put a weak reference to the classloader I can monitor when all its classes are unreachable and thus be able to reload the classes in that classloader

Comment: Eh yes, I was thinking of the wrong way around. Doesn't really make sense to have a class reloaded in the middle of some operation. Have you looked at what Spring offers that might help you? I'd really recommend doing so before you write your own classloader mechanisms. Just like you look at `java.util.concurrent` before doing `wait()/notify()` things.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance but what exactly does spring offer in this area?

I agree with you  that "doesn't really make sense to have a class reloaded int he middle of some operation". I guess that is the root of the problem in that I can't always stop the process. Ideally I need some way of saying to the VM the next time you need this class, please use this one...

Comment: See the edits to my answer. From the little I looked at it, it seemed pretty promising and it would allow you to avoid going low level unnecessarily.

Comment: @Michael Wiles: you can’t use weak references to find out when classes are “no longer in use”. The classes are, per definition, in use as long as their class loader is reachable and vice versa. But that doesn’t have to stop you from [closing the class loader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLClassLoader.html#close--) which will release the underlying resources and make, e.g. the jar file writable. Then, you can load the new classes with a new class loader, as there is no actual “reloading of classes” anyway. These classes are entirely unrelated.

Comment: @MichaelWiles The only way you can guarantee that classes are being collected is by utilizing [PhantomReference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html)s. The phantom reference though also needs to be collected else it will prevent the monitored object from bein collected. I also wrote a [plugin framework](https://github.com/RovoMe/PluginApplication) in Java for a university course which uses phantom references to check if classes got unloaded though I inject dependencies myself instead of using Spring.